# Creating a gesture definition for a simple static gesture using Kinect

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, gesture-recognition

I have created a Kinect application using the Kinect SDK and WPF in C#.

I want to create a simple static gesture recognition method that outputs a Messagebox when the user raises their 'rightHand' (`JointID.HandRight`) joint over their 'Head' (`JointID.Head`) joint at runtime.

I know that I need create a defintion for this gesture and run this against the skeletons each time the SkeletonFrameReady event is fired. Is there anyone who can help with this or point me in the right direction as to what skeleton data I need to store/compare, I would be very grateful, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you must compare the initial position of your right hand with the current position of your right hand every round of the thread. For example, if you want to see if you right hand has raised or not, you must compare x and y position. I hope that I have understood your question. Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 2):

In MS SDK V1 you must use `JointType` instead of `JointID`. Here is a very simple sample.

```
//this event fires when Color/Depth/Skeleton are synchronized
void newSensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    //Get a skeleton
    Skeleton skeleton = GetFirstSkeleton(e);

    if (skeleton == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (skeleton != null)
    {
        checkHand(skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head], skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight], skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft]);
    }
}

Skeleton GetFirstSkeleton(AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrameData = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
        if (skeletonFrameData == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        skeletonFrameData.CopySkeletonDataTo(allSkeletons);

        //get the first tracked skeleton
        Skeleton first = (from s in allSkeletons
                            where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                            select s).FirstOrDefault();

        return first;
    }
}

public void checkHand(Joint head, Joint rhand, Joint lhand)
{
    if (rhand.Position.Y > head.Position.Y)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Right hand up!");
    }
    else if (lhand.Position.Y > head.Position.Y)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Left hand up!");
    }
}
```